# Office web apps 2010 running on Sharepoint 2013 for compatibility mode sites

Tags: office-web-apps

We need to run sites in SharePoint 2010 mode as we migrate each collection and train each department. Everything works just like in real 2010 except I can't install Office Web Apps 2010, installation fails.

Does anyone know a way to maintain the same Office Web App functionality on sites running in 2010 mode on 2013?

FYI: We have office web apps 2013 installed and functional for sites in 2013 mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I dug a little deeper and found this [post on technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/cb1f4fb0-58f7-45e5-b470-92169aa38575/is-office-web-apps-2013-compatible-with-sharepoint-2010?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious).  The answer seems unfortunately that it is simply no.  This is a major flaw in the compatibility mode.  So anyway who go to upgrade to 2013 realize that if you need transition time for a site collection the users will not have access to Office Web Apps while in 2010 mode, only in 2013 mode.

Comment: Just came across this post and i am in similar situation. Is this still an issue or has a SP or CU been released? Cheers D

Answer (score 0):

That link suluger included doesn't answer or really relate to the posted question. That was referencing using SharePoint 2010 with OWA 2013 which is different to running SharePoint 2013 sites in 2010 mode with OWA 2013. The difference is a bit subtle if you're not familiar with the terms and technology but it's huge in practical terms.

SharePoint 2013 should allow the use of OWA in sites that are still running in 2010 mode. [See TechNet forum post here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e8ca1d10-0d58-4f3e-8321-7b1208fa0e02/will-office-web-apps-server-2013-work-with-sharepoint-2013-sites-hosted-in-sp2010-compatibility?forum=sharepointadmin)